Synchronization error between SQLite and SQL Server does not work in Android platform .NET maui project
I have a .NET maui project which contains a SQLite database. I want to synchronize the Categories table with a remote SQL Server, but I encounter the following error in Android platform (in Windows, it works perfectly) knowing that I used the Dotmim.Sync library:

An error occurred: [InternalEnsureScopeInfoAsync] Overwrite:False.. [InternalGetSchema Async].. [InternalGet TableSchema Async). Table:Product.. A transport level error occurred while receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 2-Connection terminated)

Here is my code:
// Class Categories
public class Categories
{
     [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string NomCategorie { get; set; }
     public string DateCreation { get; set; }
}

// Connection string for SQL Server
string connectionString = @"Data Source=SQL server ;Initial Catalog=db  ;User Id= admin;Password=Password";

// Initialization of Categories
SqlSyncProvider serverProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(connectionString);
string dbPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "mydb.db");

SqliteSyncProvider clientProvider = new SqliteSyncProvider(dbPath);

// Configuring synchronization for the "Categories" table
var setup = new SyncSetup("Categories");

// Create the synchronization agent and execute the synchronization
SyncAgent agent = new SyncAgent(clientProvider, serverProvider);
var result = await agent.SynchronizeAsync(setup);

And here is the Categories table in SQL Server:
Table categories in SQL Server
I've done several searches online but can't find any information.

https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync/issues/1106


I want to synchronize the Categories table with a remote SQL Server

Yes, just as the link above mentioned, on mobile, we can't reach a remote SQL Server instance directly, we need to use an API between our app and the SQL Service.
On Maui, you can use a REST-based web service to send data to servers or async data between them.

Representational State Transfer (REST) is an architectural style for
building web services. REST requests are typically made over HTTPS
using the same HTTP verbs that web browsers use to retrieve web pages
and to send data to servers.

And REST-based web services typically use JSON messages to return data to the client.
For more information, you can check document: Consume a REST-based web service.
